# ASP.NET convert date from yyyyMMdd to dd MMM yyyy code behind

Tags: code-behind, date-conversion

Can you help me how to convert date from **yyyyMMdd** to **dd MMM yyyy** with code behind?
I have date value `20151012`, I need to convert to `12 Oct 2015`.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
public Datetime dateVariable{get;set;}    
public string strVariable {get;set;}   

strVariable=dateVariable.tostring("DD mmm yyyy");
```

Comment: Yes, what are you looking for? @Emma

Comment: I'm using vb.net. I think it uses a different syntax @metaphor.

Comment: strVariable=dateVariable.tostring("DD mmm yyyy"); will be unchanged. And I think you had a Datetime type variable, so, you have to declare another string type variable. That's it.